# grails transactional service not saving domain object [v2.5.6]

Tags: grails, transactions, grails-orm, ehcache

I have a grails (version 2.5.6) service creating and trying to save a domain object.
Although it answers the saved object I don't retrieve it in db or query

I have set :
grails.gorm.failOnError=true in Config.groovy

static transactional = true in service

```
biz.Forecast forecast = new biz.Forecast()
forecast.security = security
forecast.estimation = somevalue
forecast.era = (era2 - 1)
forecast.maxdate = nth.toInteger()
forecast.dateOfVolume = dtfOut.print(new DateTime().minusDays((era2 - 1)))
forecast.save(flush: true)
log.error(forecast.errors)
log.error(forecast)
```

grails.validation.ValidationErrors: 0 errors

Security: ACA -- date: 2019-09-06 -- maxDate: 24

EDIT: domain classes: biz.Forecast

```
package biz

class Forecast {
    static hasOne = [security:Security]
    // era is 24 or 72
    int era
    // maxdate is
    int maxdate
    String dateOfVolume
    double estimation
    static constraints = {
    }
    String toString(){
        return "Security: ${security.name} -- date: ${dateOfVolume} -- maxDate: ${maxdate}"
    }
}
```

and biz.Security

```
package biz

import java.math.BigDecimal;


class Security {
    String name
    String description
    String exchange
    String type
    String full_name

    static hasMany = [infos: Information,forecasts:Forecast]
    public String toString(){
        return "${name}- ${exchange}--${full_name}"  
    }
    static constraints = {
        name nullable: false,blank: false,unique: true
        exchange nullable: false,blank: false
        type nullable: false,blank: false
        description blank: true,nullable: true
        full_name nullable: false,blank: false
    }
}
```